# SMPP Invalid destination address submitting international message

Tags: java, smpp

Good day guys!. I'm having a problem trying to submit an international sms vía SMPP (using Logica Java library). I'm gonna summarize the tests I've done. I'm using WireShark to monitor SMPP related activities.

1. (Working)

   ```
       //Connect and stablish session
       Connection conn = new TCPIPConnection(providerAddress, port);
       Session session = new Session(conn);
       BindRequest breq = new BindTransmitter();
       breq.setSystemId(user);
       breq.setPassword(pass);
       breq.setSystemType("CMT");
       breq.setInterfaceVersion((byte)34);
       breq.setAddressRange((byte)0x01, (byte)0x01,null);
       Response resp = session.bind(breq);

       //Create message
       SubmitSM msg = new SubmitSM();
       msg.setDestAddr((byte)1, (byte)1, "58412014XXXX");
       msg.setSourceAddr((byte)1, (byte)1, "58412014XXXX");
       msg.setShortMessage("Test from tedexis","ISO-8859-1");  

       //Here we submit message
       session.submit(msg);

       //Disconnect
       session.unbind();
   ```

Result:  Message is delivered correctly. Here we validate credentials are valid, and notice the source and destination addresses are the same

1. (Failing) The code remains the same except for the message destination address which is now set for an INTERNATIONAL PHONE NUMBER

   ```
       msg.setSourceAddr((byte)1, (byte)1, "1321237XXXX");
   ```

Result: Fails, checking WireShark I observe the following exception during the submit:
**SMPP Submit_sm - resp: "Invalid destination address"**

We may think that our credentials are not valid for international deliveries but we are currently using these credentials delivering international messages through their webservice interface.

I must be missing a configuration setting or wrongly setting one already, but I ran out of ideas, if anyone can point me in the right direction I would be glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you dont have to set your address range since you're binding as a transmitter, because the address range is used to inform the SMSC that this 'receiver' session will handle MO messages from the desired address range.

As for sending to international numbers, i'm not into logica's API but i'm pretty sure that you're missing to set the destination address ton to 1 (international number) and the destination address npi to 0 (Unknown) or 1 (ISDN) and retry the sending.

If the error persists, you'll have to call your provider, it is possible that they gave you the permission to send to international numbers through webservice only.